# Bespin php backend how to?

Tags: php, editor, edit, bespin

Do any body know how to use bespin php backend? mean how can i use it , i want to edit php files like an online php code editor.http://launchpad.net/bespinphp here is the url!!

Answer (score 1):

As they say, just download their zip file onto your PHP server, unzip it, and then run the installation script. I tried it and found it pretty easy. Once it's running, you can type "help" into the console to see the commands available to you. I was able to use createproject and newfile, but actually running my code didn't seem to work. It's just a 0.2 release, so I'm not terribly surprised.